# How to reuse channel layouts?

Tags: channel, layouts

I'd like to import a custom channel layout into another channel that uses the same fieldset. Is there an easy way to do this?

Using EE 5.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this I've found is to:

1. Create a layout for your new channel
2. Go into exp_channel_layouts and grab the field_layout field from your original layout
3. Copy the contents of this into your new layout's field_layout field

As long as it's the same fieldset, it should work.